# How to check if directories starting with a particular string exist or not?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What command can be used to check if  directories starting with a particular pattern exists or not, within  shell script ?

For example :

In HOME path if there are many directories starting with ABCD_* and i want to check if there are any directories staring with pattern- ABCD_* exist or not using a command.

`If (any directory matching this pattern exist) then echo found else echo not found  fi`

Comment: In `bash` you cannot return `true` or `false`. Do you mean the status codes `0` and `1` or do you want to print something?

Comment: @Socowi Yes, that will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
find ~ -type d -name "ABCD_*"
```

Search the home directory of the current user (~) for directories (-type d) with the pattern "ABCD_*" (using -name)

You can then use this in an if condition by integrating it with wc -l and so:

```
if [[ "$(find ~ -type d -name "ABCD_*" | wc -l)"  -gt "0" ]];
then 
    echo "Found";
else
    echo "Not Found";
fi
```

Comment: Hi @Raman thanks for the answer. This will print the path and list of directories matching this condition. What i want is a boolean value whether it is present or not.

Comment: @AtifSheikh you simply need to wrap the code you've been provided with in an if statement.

Comment: Hi @arco44 i am already using this. I am using if condition and if found then it is printing path and then executing business logic. I dont want that.

Comment: I've added an if condition

Answer (score 0):

Use a glob and count the number of matches. To ensure that only directories are matched, use a trailing `/`.

Counting can be done with arrays ...

```
shopt -s nullglob
found=(~/ABCD_*/)
if (( "${#found[@]}" > 0 )); then
  # there are directories starting with ABCD_
else
  # there are no such directories
fi
```

... or by a function ...

```
hasArgs() {
  (( $# > 0 ))
}
shopt -s nullglob
if hasArgs ~/ABCD_*/; then
  # there are directories starting with ABCD_
else
  # there are no such directories
fi
```